# Flagged link-only answer as NAA, flag declined but moderator deleted the question

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, not-an-answer, link-only-answers

I'm curious about why this just happened. I came across a three year-old question basically asking for library recommendations. The question had been closed for quite some time.

It had two answers. One was accepted with one up vote. That answer only had links to a few offsite libraries.

Here's the now deleted answer:

---

This are the list of Free excel file creator... Give it a try

ObjC++ wrapper and framework to construct Microsoft Excel

http://sourceforge.net/projects/xlslib/

https://github.com/JanX2/JXLS

This is the link of open source project, it may help you-:

https://github.com/andreac/RSSheet

---

I flagged the answer as "not an answer".

The flag was declined but the moderator deleted the whole question.

Why not mark my flag as helpful if the whole question should have been deleted? Wasn't my marking of the poor answer helpful in removing a bad question?

Comment: *"The only real text in the answer was the library names."* - And that is an answer. You still can downvote it for being an answer for an off-topic question, if you like, but a NAA flag is not valid here.

Comment: It was not the right flag I'd expect. It was an answer, trying to answer the post. Sure, it was a low quality answer to a question that should have been deleted, but it was an answer nonetheless.

Comment: I've had scores of NAA flags marked as helpful with the given answer deleted for answers that only had links and the text with the associate library/software name. I guess different mods handle such flags differently. But I still don't understand this situation. The flag is declined meaning the mod thinks the answer is an answer. It was an accepted answer so it was also helpful to someone. But the same mod then chose to delete the whole question. Seems odd.

Comment: @Tom Actually, I just updated my question with the answer. It did not have the library names, just links and some filler text.

Comment: @Oded See my update with the answer. It was just links.

Comment: Well, one could argue that in these links is also the lib name and that is sufficient enough. The thing is, you must imagine the post without the link, but keep the link text (i.e. just remove the `<a>` tags). Low quality answer, sure, that sadly still a valid answer for Stack Overflow.

Comment: If the question is asking for garbage, don't you think it would be more important to delete the question (in-turn deleting the garbage) instead of flagging an individual garbage answer? See also: [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370). This answer does not qualify as a link-only answer when those guidelines are applied. That you have had flags on similar answers (not non-answers) marked helpful may or may not be a problem depending on the specific answers flagged. It's not a valuable answer, but should not be flagged.

Answer (score 5):

Please don't flag answers to requests for a library. The answer clearly answered the question, it was the *question* that was the problem.

If you were having issues with that answer, why didn't you also look at the *other* answer to the question, the one that vaguely hints that some Excel files are XML, then linking to "wikipedia" without showing what article on Wikipedia it linked to? That post was of far lower quality, in the context of the question.

I deleted the question because, being closed, the question and answers are only going to get outdated, fast, *and* to avoid further flagging. It sat around on Stack for 3.5 years with a score of -1 and only 2.5k views. It simply didn't need to stay.

Comment: I didn't really read the question. I came across the answer first. Saw that it was a link-only answer and I flagged it. I glanced at the other answer enough to see it wasn't just a bunch of links and I left it alone. I didn't pay more attention until after my flag was declined and I saw that you had deleted the question. We are told over and over to treat answers on their own and questions on their own. I flagged what I thought was a bad answer independent of the question. Is that wrong? And for the record, I fully agree that the question should be deleted. I have no issue with that.

Comment: Vote on individual posts based on their own merits (i.e. don't downvote good answers to bad questions). When it comes to making work for others, you want to minimize the amount of work while maximizing the gain. If the question is a tool request and it is attracting link only or otherwise low quality answers, the best bang for buck would be to get rid of the question. Treat the problem, not the symptom. @rmaddy.

Comment: @rmaddy: I'm not sure where it states you need to treat answers on their own; we regularly look at an answer in the context of a question. The two are (hopefully) closely linked. *Voting* should be done on the quality of the post itself, not based on the (other) answers or the question, but when flagging answers, do check what the question asked for.

Comment: Similarly, answers to tool request questions cannot possibly be spam _because_ the question is asking for spam. (i.e. the primary criterion for it being spam is that it is an **unsolicited** advertisement, if the question is soliciting advertisements, it cannot be spam). @rmaddy

Comment: @TinyGiant Who said anything about spam?

Comment: @rmaddy: Plenty of people use spam flags on answers to software requests, which we then decline. I don't think Tiny was thinking *you* do that.

Comment: @MartijnPieters What should I have done to get the question removed? It was closed a long time ago. It only had one down vote so the delete link wasn't visible. Simply down voting the question wouldn't have accomplished anything. Seems to me that flagging the bad answer gave the proper result in the end. The bad answer and the question are now gone.

Comment: @rmaddy: But it did not require deleting, the post was not causing more problems. It was already closed, it had a low view count. It could have existed on the site for a bit longer. If you had downvoted it, it would have given a next visitor an indication the post was probably not going to be helpful, and perhaps they'd have voted too, etc.

Comment: @rmaddy: I only deleted it because the *flagging* was a problem. Don't take that as a sign that flagging for the wrong reasons is a good way to get a post deleted.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Are you saying you only deleted the question because my flag on the answer wasn't appropriate? That doesn't seem right. And don't worry, I have no intention of misflagging answers with the goal of getting the question deleted.

Comment: @MartijnPieters  I still believe my flag on the answer was valid. Remove the links and the answer provides no information of any kind. That's what NAA flags are for, right? The deletion of the answer by you is just secondary and independent of my rejected flag.

Comment: @rmaddy no the answer was an answer, it just so happens to be an answer that is likely to be flagged incorrectly in the future. Seeing as the entire Q&A offered very little in the way of value, deleting the question was appropriate even if only to prevent further inappropriate flags on the answers.

Comment: @TinyGiant Ignoring everything else, just looking at the answer on its own, are you saying that the answer I flagged is really an answer? Look at the quoted answer in my question. Remove the links. Look at what is left. Are you saying that the remaining answer is in any way an answer? Clearly I don't think it's an answer and that's why I flagged is as "not an answer".

Comment: @rmaddy yes I'm saying it is an answer based on the answer-castle guidance I linked above in a comment on your question.